# XCode Storyboards Slow and Unresponsive

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

After some typical changes to update an image, working in the main storyboard is almost impossible because Xcode is so slow.

Reverting the commit fixes the slowness. However, I am unsure what changes resulted in the slowness.

XCODE: 13.1

MacOS: BigSur

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue myself, XCode apparently changed (in the background) the `inferredMetricsTieBreakers` segue references.

Viewing the storyboard as code, I removed these. Then, reopened in Interface Builder and these references were automatically regenerated. That solved the Interface Builder slowness!

The article provides more helpful information: https://medium.com/@mzygar/resolving-storyboard-merge-conflicts-94eae558acb8.